# rhel 6 default gateway not working

Tags: networking, rhel, networkmanager

I have six similar **RHEL 6** servers in the lab and the settings are same in all the servers. The settings are,

```
static IP address: 129.XXX.XXX.XX
Subnet Mask: 255.255.254.0
Default Gateway: 129.XXX.XXX.1
```

My default gateway has suddenly stopped working in one of the servers (*server1*) and am investigating what caused this issue.

Now, if I do `route -n` in *server1*, I get the output as,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
129.XXX.XXX.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

I suspected it could be firewall issue but I checked with the school network and the firewall is configured correctly. My `/etc/hosts` file is as below.

```
127.0.0.1   server1.xxx.edu        localhost
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` is as below.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search xxx.edu. xxx.edu
nameserver 129.xxx.xx.xx
```

In *server2* which belongs to the same network as *server1*, `route -n` gives the output as below.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
129.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         129.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
```

I am trying to figure out if am missing something else.

**EDIT**

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` on *server1*,

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server1.xxx.edu
GATEWAY=255.255.254.0
```

**Edit 2:**

After I changed the default gateway, if I execute `route -n` command the output is as below.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
129.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
```

I also tried removing the default gateway entry in the `/etc/sysconfig/networks` file as well. But I get the same output for `route -n` as above.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=129.xxx.xxx.xx
PREFIX=23
GATEWAY=129.xxx.xxx.1
DNS1=129.xxx.xx.xx
DOMAIN=xxx.edu.
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
LAST_CONNECT=1406927310
```

Comment: On server1, what is content of `/etc/sysconfig/network`?

Comment: @Gnouc, please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an invalid `GATEWAY` value in [/etc/sysconfig/network](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-network.html) for `server1`. So, change it to your gateway ip address:

```
GATEWAY=129.XXX.XXX.1
```

Save file, restart networking service to make the change.

Comment: thanks. As soon as posted the edit I tried out that option. But unfortunately it seems to not work.

Comment: @Ramesh: Did you restart networking service?

Comment: no luck. I tried rebooting the machine as well.

Comment: How route table look like after you restart? And did you check config file of your network card? `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`

Comment: thanks for providing more info. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: @Ramesh: What happen if you try adding gateway manually?

Comment: it works. However, if I restart the network services, it disappears. I already tried to make this setting permenant in `/etc/sysconfig/network` but unfortunately it is messing up.

Comment: Strange. Do you have any other network script for other network card that set default gateway?

Comment: @Ramesh: And try add this `GATEWAYDEV=eth0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the correct answer was voted down, but "DEFROUTE=no" in the ifcfg-eth0 file means that this interface won't have the default route (it assumes some other interface may).

Change to DEFROUTE="yes" (and restart networking) and the default route should stick.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
defroute=yes
```

and if ipv6 is present:

```
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
```